# Service Windows Java using JavaExe not running by default

Tags: java, windows, service, jar

I'm using JavaExe to create a Windows Service from my jar file.
I renamed the javaexe.exe to "Server.exe" where "Server" is the name of my only jar file.

When I try to run the exe file, the service is correctly created on Windows and does not stop when closing the session. However, when I reboot Windows, the service is not running (I can see it on Windows services but not running).

What I would like to do is to **allow the service to be running when Windows starts**... Is it possible ? I guess this is something in the ".properties" file but I can't seem to find the correct property...

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read the doc : [**FR**](http://devwizard.free.fr/doc/JavaExe%20-%20fr.pdf) or [**ENG**](http://devwizard.free.fr/doc/JavaExe%20-%20en.pdf)

there are some methods to declare, like **serviceGetInfo()** to tell to JavaExe the start Type of service and it can be stopped or not.

...and look examples (3, 5 and 8) in [**JavaExe.zip**](http://devwizard.free.fr/download/JavaExe.zip)